# Is it bad to store images as Data URIs in a database BLOB?

Tags: html, mysql, image, blob, innodb

I'm creating a mobile app that views articles. These articles are just simple html with a couple of images each. I am currently storing everything in a database. Later, I will need to save the articles locally to the device in an easy format. For this reason, I have opted to store the Base64 images within the database, using a Data URI Scheme (look here for info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

My question is: is it okay to store this much data in one database entry? I have a table that is ONLY for these large records, with article meta data tables that point to these. Would it be better if I used TEXT fields, rather than BLOBs?

If it helps, I am using MySQL with the InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding using the db to store images is a good practice, keeping the images in the db not only slows down your db performance it also increases it size and backups, if you are using cloud service then there is also the cost issue.

Use S3 or Azure for this purpose and have only the url of the images in your db.Files may be uploaded directly to to the storage service reducing load on your db server. The only thing left to do is for your mobile application to connect both this services(db and the Images service),i found [this web  tool](https://www.backand.com/) to manage my mobile app db because it connect to my Images cloud service which is Azure but i think they also support Amazon S3.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to store images in something like:

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

and then just have a field in your database that stored the url for each image.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you dont have a DB as big as facebook or similar it should be fine. 
It is best to store just the path to the image and the image themselves in a folder.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into Azure Blob Storage. I've been using it and it's working very well.